# Average Length of Google

Tags: code-golf, internet

I was messing around with Pyth's url request feature, and noticed that google always gave a response with a slightly different length for me, usually `~10500` characters.

So your task in this challenge is to print out the average length of the html response from `http://google.com`.

## Specs

- You will take an input `n` which is the number of requests to make.
- For each request, you will make an HTTP get request.
- You will count the response body (the html text), not the headers.
- Output the arithmetic mean of the lengths of the responses.
- You can only access the url `http://google.com`, not any other.
- This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so shortest code in **bytes** wins!

**Sample output for input `10`:** `10560.1`

(I used Python's `urllib` for that)

**P.S: does anyone know why google does this?**

Comment: Strange, `http://google.com` always returns 261 bytes for me... `https://google.com/ncr` might return more though.

Comment: @Neil Odd, `http://google.com` always returns 10422 bytes for me...

Comment: Can a ratio of integers (i.e., an exact fraction) be returned?

Comment: @LegionMammal978 no, sorry.

Comment: @Neil You get 261 bytes because you actually receive an URL redirection, code 302, which has in the body the new URL to follow. Some programs, like curl on linux, need a specific argument to follow that new URL automatically.

Comment: @seshoumara TBH the challenge does not specify to follow redirections, so I would expect Neil's answer to be the correct answer by default, since it handles the actual HTTP response that `http://google.com` sends. Of course this isn't the point of the challenge, so the challenge should IMO be edited to reflect that.

Comment: @Aaron I agree, my comment above was more of an explanation to why he felt it was strange getting 261 bytes. I should have not mentioned the second part, but I was writing my own answer at that time with redirection, so I didn't realized it wasn't actually necessary.

Comment: Which average?`

Comment: @theonlygusti the arithmtic mean

Answer (score 21):

### Bash + system utilities, <s>56</s> <s>53</s> <s>49</s> 48 bytes

*Update:* saved 4 bytes thanks to [Digital Trauma](/users/11259/digital-trauma) and 1 byte more thanks to [Dennis](/users/12012/dennis)

```sh
curl -L `yes google.com|sed $1q`|wc|dc -e1k?$1/p
```

In my original answer I was using `yes` in combination with `xargs` to emulate a for loop. But `curl` can accept as input a list of URLs, so only the output from `yes` is actually needed.

When `curl` accesses *google.com*, it receives a 302 redirection page that has the new URL in the body section, so the `-L` option is needed to follow it.

**Run example:** answer is printed to STDOUT, I redirect STDERR just for clarity

```sh
me@LCARS:/PPCG$ ./google_length.sh "8" 2> /dev/null
10583.2
```

**Explanation:** (of the initially submitted code)

```sh
yes google.com|     # repeatedly output a line containing the string "google.com"
sed $1q|            # print the first $1 lines only (shorter than head -$1)
xargs curl -sL|     # xargs reads the input lines and executes "curl -sL" with the
                    #current input line as an additional argument.
wc -m|              # count the number of characters
dc -e1k?$1/p        # dc script: set precision to 1, read input, push $1 and divide
```

**Edit:** I replaced `wc -m` with `wc`, because even if without arguments it prints 2 more statistics than the one I wanted, the same `dc` script following this output still works, because the count we want is, happily, placed on top of the stack during parsing.

Comment: @DigitalTrauma Very nice, no need for `xargs`. Thanks, I updated the answer.

Comment: You don't need `-s`. Stray output to STDERR is allowed by default.

Comment: @Dennis Thanks, answer updated.

Answer (score 17):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 28 bytes

```
:"'http://google.com'Xin]vYm
```

Gif or it didn't happen:

[image]

#### How it works

```
:                      % Implicitly input n. Push [1 2 ... n]
"                      % For each
  'http://google.com'  %   Push this string
  Xi                   %   URL read. Gives a string
  n                    %   Number of elements
]                      % End
v                      % Concatenate stack contents into a vertical vector
Ym                     % Mean. Implicitly display
```

Answer (score 13):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell), 48 bytes

```powershell
1.."$args"|%{irm google.com}|measure Le* -a|% A*
```

### Explanation

1. Create a range from `1` to the input integer.
2. For each value in the range `Invoke-RestMethod` (`irm`) the google homepage. The result is not JSON so it will return the body verbatim instead of deserializing it.
3. Send that to `Measure-Object` (`measure`), getting an average of the `Length` property of the input strings (the bodies).
4. Expand the resulting `Average` property.

Comment: did not know `|% A*` was possible, i've always avoided `measure` because I thought you couldn't wildcard the property name...

Comment: @ConnorLSW yeah this is something I discovered recently while preparing a presentation on code golf in PowerShell. Check out `|? A*` for some cool stuff as well. I need to look at my presentation files and add this stuff to the tips thread.

Comment: @ConnorLSW [added some detailed info on these usages in the tips page](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/111526/30402).

Answer (score 11):

## Java 8, <strike>197</strike> <strike>184</strike> <strike>182</strike> 181 bytes

Golfed:

```java
n->{int s=0,i=0;while(i++<n)try{s+=new java.util.Scanner(new java.net.URL("http://google.com").openStream()).useDelimiter("\\A").next().length();}catch(Exception e){}return s*1f/n;}
```

Ungolfed:

```java
public class AverageLengthOfGoogle {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    float bytes = f(n -> {
      int s = 0, i = 0;
      while (i++ < n) {
        try {
          s += new java.util.Scanner(new java.net.URL("http://google.com").openStream())
              .useDelimiter("\\A").next().length();
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
        }
      }
      return s * 1f / n;
    } , 10);
    System.out.println(bytes);
  }

  private static float f(java.util.function.IntFunction<Float> f, int n) {
    return f.apply(n);
  }
}
```

This leaks resources, but that is a small price to pay in search of the fewest bytes.

Comment: Possible improvements:
1. double -> float
2. http://www.google.com -> http://google.com
3. maybe specifying encoding is not necessary, there should be some deprecated method
You should save some 20 bytes

Comment: @kukis thanks, that shaved off 13 bytes.

Comment: `n->{int s=0,i=0;for(;i<n;++i)try{...}catch(Exception e){}return s*1.0/n;}`. Not sure whether you can replace `s*1.0/n` in the return with `s*1f/n`, but it's worth a try

Comment: @RomanGräf yes, that works. Thanks!

Comment: `for(;i<n;++i)` can be changed to `for(;i++<n;)` for -1 byte.

Comment: You can save 2 bytes by changing 
    System.out.println(bytes); to
    System.out.print(bytes);

Comment: @KBusc the `main` method as a whole is not included in the byte count for golfing purpose. Only the lambda counts, and it simply returns the value which is allowed in these competitions unless otherwise specified. So `println()` has no bearing on the score for the function I wrote. Besides, Java is inconsistent with flushing the buffer before the program terminates: sometimes it will, sometimes it will not.

Answer (score 8):

## PHP, <s>90</s> 78 bytes

```
while($i++<$argv[1]){$s+=strlen(file_get_contents('http://google.com'));}echo $s/$argv[1];
```

```
while($i++<$argv[1])$s+=strlen(join(file('http://google.com')));echo$s/($i-1);
```

- Used shorter functions/variables and removed unnecessary syntactic construct as mentioned by commenters

Comment: Wellcome to codegolf.se ! `join(file())` instead of `file_get_contents()` saves you a few bytes.

Comment: In addition you can drop the curly braces and the space after the `echo`. Also you can use `$i` instead of `$argv[1]` as the divisor.

Answer (score 8):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 15 bytes

Code:

```
F’Š¹.ŒŒ’.wgO}¹/
```

Explanation:

```
F           }     # Input times do..
 ’Š¹.ŒŒ’          #   Push the string "google.com"
        .w        #   Read all and wrap into a string
          g       #   Get the length
           O      #   Sum it up with the total
             ¹/   # Divide by input
```

Uses the **CP-1252** encoding. When run in the offline interpreter I get the following:

```
> py -3 05AB1E.py -c test.abe
1
11039.0

> py -3 05AB1E.py -c test.abe
2
11070.0

> py -3 05AB1E.py -c test.abe
3
11046.666666666666

> py -3 05AB1E.py -c test.abe
4
11029.75

> py -3 05AB1E.py -c test.abe
5
11015.8
```

Comment: Either you have a built-in for google.com or something else is going on!

Comment: @Pureferret It's actually a dictionary compressed string. You can try it out [here](https://tio.run/nexus/05ab1e#@/@oYebRBYd26h2ddHQSkP3/PwA) :).

Comment: Is using languages dedicated to golfing allowed? If so, then I can theoretically make up language that will do all of these things in one byte

Comment: @kukis Using dedicated golfing languages are allowed, _if and only if_ the language version that is used doesn't postdate the challenge. If you make up a language that can do all these things in one byte, but the compiler was made after the challenge, it is a violation of both [this](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/1071/34388) and [this](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/5800/34388).

Answer (score 7):

## Pyth, 25 bytes

```
.OmslM'"http://google.com
```

`'` is the open function in Pyth, and when given a string starting with `http`, it performs a GET resuest to that website. The return value is a list of `bytes` objects. Unfortunately, Pyth's `s` doesn't know how to concatenate these objects, so instead of `ls`, I use `slM` to get the total length. This is performed a number of times equal to the input by `m`, and the results are averaged by `.O`.

Answer (score 6):

## Mathematica, 58 bytes

```
N@Mean[StringLength@URLFetch@"http://google.com"~Table~#]&
```

Anonymous function. Takes a number as input, and returns a number as output.

Comment: Why do you need `N@`? You aren't printing it, so there's no reason to format it nicely.

Comment: @Pavel OP specified that exact fractions aren't allowed.

Answer (score 3):

## Python, 102 bytes

```python
import urllib2
f=lambda n:sum([len(urllib2.urlopen(x).read()) for x in ['http://google.com']*n],0.0)/n
```

Or, if we can return integers rather than floats, the answer can be 98 bytes:

```python
import urllib2
f=lambda n:sum([len(urllib2.urlopen(x).read()) for x in ['http://google.com']*n])/n
```

Comment: You can remove a couple spaces in there. `)for x in[`. Also, if you restrict yourself to Python 3, the division will automatically be float division, and you can remove `0.0`.

Comment: You also don't need the `[]` in the 2nd case - `sum` takes a `generator`

Answer (score 3):

## [CJam](https://sourceforge.net/p/cjam), 23 bytes

```
rd_"google.com"a*:gs,\/
```

Doesn't work on TIO for security reasons.

#### Test run

```
$ echo -n 'rd_"google.com"a*:gs,\/' > google-avg.cjam
$ wc -c google-avg.cjam
23 google-avg.cjam
$ java -jar cjam-0.6.5.jar google-avg.cjam <<< 10; echo
10663.2
$ java -jar cjam-0.6.5.jar google-avg.cjam <<< 10; echo
10650.0
$ java -jar cjam-0.6.5.jar google-avg.cjam <<< 10; echo
10651.0
$ java -jar cjam-0.6.5.jar google-avg.cjam <<< 10; echo
10651.4
$ java -jar cjam-0.6.5.jar google-avg.cjam <<< 10; echo
10673.5
```

#### How it works

```
 rd                      e# Read a double from STDIN. Let's call it D.
   _                     e# Push a copy of D.
    "google.com"a        e# Wrap the string in an array, pushing ["google.com"].
                 *       e# Repeat the array D times.
                  :g     e# Map `get` over the array, making D requests to the URL.
                    s    e# Combine all D responses into a single string.
                     ,   e# Compute the length.
                      \  e# Swap the length with the original D.
                       / e# Perform division.
```

Answer (score 2):

## Clojure, 102 bytes

```
(fn[n](/(reduce + 0.0(repeatedly n #(count(slurp(clojure.java.io/reader"http://www.google.com")))))n))
```

Ungolfed:

```
(fn [n]
  (/
   (reduce + 0.0
           (repeatedly n
                       #(count (slurp (clojure.java.io/reader "http://www.google.com")))))
   n))
```

`#(count (slurp (clojure.java.io/reader "http://www.google.com")))` is a local function which counts the bytes from an http request to google, `repeatedly` calls the function n times and makes a list from the returned counts, reduce sums the results together, and finally that is divided by n to make an average. The reduce is started at 0.0 to force the result into a float- otherwise the division would result in a rational. Whole thing is wrapped in an anonymous function which takes the number of times to name the request.

Comment: I swear I didn't copy this answer! Mine ended up quite close to yours. The `(clojure.java.io/reader)` part is unnecessary btw. It's done automatically behind the scenes if you pass a string.

Answer (score 2):

## Python 3, 95 bytes

Recursive solution

```
import requests as r
f=lambda n,t:f(n-1,t+len(r.get('http://google.com').text)) if n>0 else t/i
```

where `n=i=int(input())`

[requests library](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/install/#install)

Comment: Requests seems to be an external library, so you'll want to add a link to that. Something like `Python 3 + [Requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/install/#install), 95 bytes`

Comment: `urllib2` is a native (pre-installed) Python library https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib2.html so anyone downloading Python can immediately run their code. I can't run your code on my Python 3 without that library.

Comment: @ValueInk no problem, my first contribution here, I didn't know

Answer (score 2):

## Perl, 66 bytes

```
perl -MLWP::Simple -pe'map$t+=length get"http://google.com",1..$_;$_=$t/$_'
```

51 bytes + 14 bytes for `-MLWP::Simple<space>` + 1 byte for `-p`.

Straightforward solution using [LWP::Simple](https://metacpan.org/pod/LWP::Simple). The `get` function is exported by default and returns the response content on success.

## Perl 5.14+, <s>94</s> 93 bytes (core modules only)

```
perl -MHTTP::Tiny -pe'map$t+=length${+get{new HTTP::Tiny}"http://google.com"}{content},1..$_;$_=$t/$_'
```

79 bytes + 13 bytes for `-MHTTP::Tiny<space>` + 1 byte for `-p`.

Uses [HTTP::Tiny](https://metacpan.org/pod/HTTP::Tiny), which has been in core since Perl 5.14.

### How it works

This:

```
get{new HTTP::Tiny}"http://google.com"
```

is the [indirect object syntax](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlobj.html#Indirect-Object-Syntax) equivalent of this:

```
HTTP::Tiny->new->get("http://google.com")
```

and saves three bytes. The `get` method returns a hashref with the content stored under the `content` key.

To get the actual response content, we do:

```
${+get{new HTTP::Tiny}"http://google.com"}{content}
```

which is equivalent to:

```
(get{new HTTP::Tiny}"http://google.com")->{content}
```

but saves one byte when we add `length`:

```
length(foo)->{bar}  # wrong, equivalent to (length(foo))->{bar}
length+(foo)->{bar}
length${+foo}{bar}
```

Answer (score 1):

## CJam, 27 bytes

```
{"google.com"g,}ri*]_:+\,d/
```

CJam assumes HTTP if not specified.

**Explanation**

```
{"google.com"g,}             A block which fetches from http://google.com and gets its length
                ri*          Run this block a number of times equal to the input
                   ]         Collect all the results in an array
                    _        Duplicate the array
                     :+      Sum it
                       \     Swap back to the original array
                        ,    Get its length
                         d/  Cast to double and divide 
                              (without casting, it would be integer division)
```

Answer (score 1):

## Rebol, 69 bytes

```
n: 0 loop i: do input[n: n + length? read http://www.google.com]n / i
```

Answer (score 1):

## Clojure, 70 bytes

```clj
#(/(reduce(fn[a _](+ a(count(slurp"http://google.com"))))0(range %))%)
```

A fold over a `n` long range. Sums the length of each request, then divides it by number of requests. Due to the way Clojure handles division, this returns a fraction, not a decimal. If this is unacceptable, I can fix it at the cost of a couple bytes.

```clj
(defn avg-request-len [n]
  (/
    (reduce (fn [acc _]
              (+ acc (count (slurp "http://google.com"))))
            0
            (range n))
    n))
```

Answer (score 1):

## Ruby, 73 + 10 = 83 bytes

Uses the `-rnet/http` flag.

```
->n{s=0.0;n.times{s+=Net::HTTP.get(URI"http://www.google.com").size};s/n}
```

Answer (score 1):

## Common Lisp + [quicklisp](http://quicklisp.org)/[dexador](https://github.com/fukamachi/dexador), 23 + 72 = 95 bytes

If quicklisp is installed on the system it will download and install dexador as neccesary.

Prelude:

```
(ql:quickload :dexador)
```

Code

```
(lambda(n)(/(loop :repeat n :sum(length(dex:get"http://google.com")))n))
```

Ungolfed:

```
(lambda (n)
  (/ (loop :repeat n 
           :sum (length (dex:get "http://google.com")))
     n))
```

Explaination

`(dex:get "http://google.com")`

This performs the web request to google and returns five values:

1. The web request itself as a string or byte array (depending on content type)
2. The http status code
3. A hash map of the http response headers
4. A QURI object representing the final URI after resolving redirects
5. The socket used to communicate with the web server (if it wasn't closed by the server or one of the optional args to the function)

`(length (dex:get ...))`

If you don't explicity request otherwise, Common Lisp will discard all the return values other than the first, so the length function only sees the http response itself and returns the length of this string.

`(loop :repeat n :sum (length ...))`

This calculates the response length n times and adds them.

`(/ (loop ...) n)`

This divides the summed lengths by n to compute the average.

`(lambda (n) ...)`

This wraps the body of code in an anonymous function which takes n as an argument and returns the average response length for n web requests to http://google.com.

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 14 bytes

```
’Š¹.ŒŒ’и.w€gÅA
```

```
’...’и.w€gÅA  # trimmed program
          ÅA  # mean of elements of...
         g    # lengths of...
        €     # each element of...
      .w      # content of responses from urls...
              # (implicit) "http://" concatenated with each element of...
     и        # list of...
              # implicit input...
’...’         # "google.com"...
     и        # s
              # implicit output
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 9 bytes

```
ƛ`‹`¨UL;ṁ
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCLGm2DigLlgwqhVTDvhuYEiLCIiLCIiXQ==)

The joys of the [short dictionary](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/238374/78850).

### Explained

```
ƛ`‹`¨UL;ṁ
ƛ      ;      # over the range [1, input]:
 `‹`          #     push "https://www.google.com" and
    ¨U        #     do a GET request
      L       #     taking the length of the result
        ;ṁ   # take the average of that list
```

Comment: when the 05AB1E ties the vyxal beats 05AB1E ‎

Comment: @makonede I don't think it do

Comment: It beats your answer now actually since you're sending a GET request to `http://?<!`.

Comment: @makonede wdym? Looks like I'm sending a get request to google to me